# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Virtualbox prerequisites

Tags: virtualbox

I am reading the [Virtualbox user manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#install-linux-host) which says that `Qt 5.3.2` or later (`Qt 5.6.2` or later is recommended) should be installed alongside `SDL 1.2.7` or later. How can I check what version of `Qt` is installed in my `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` system?

I tried the following command to check the installed `SDL` version:

```
$ dpkg -l sdl
dpkg-query: no packages found matching sdl
```

In the [Virtualbox website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) is described how to add Oracle repositories to Debian-based Linux distributions. If I follow those instructions will all the dependancies be installed, included `QT` and `SDL`?

I wonder if instead it might be preferable to install Virtualbox from the official Ubuntu repositories. What prevents me to make this choice are some negative reviews from `Ubuntu software`.

Comment: You should not care about the dependencies of the virtualbox package. The APT will do it in any case - the package from repository and/or the deb-package from VirtualBox [web site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)... If you are trying to build it from source - then `apt-get build-dep` will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check qt version:

```
qmake --version
```

If it spouts `qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory` error, please install:

```
sudo apt install qt4-qmake
```

The sdl libraries package is called `libsdl` and is not `sdl`, the website even mention this.

> SDL 1.2.7 or later. This graphics library is typically called **`libsdl`** or similar.

If you installing VirtualBox from Oracle repositories—yes you will also install SDL and qt, you can check this from:

```
apt-cache depends virtualbox-6.0
```

Comment: The output of `qmake --version` is: `Command "qmake" not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install qtchooser`.

Comment: In that case, please try install `qtchooser`

Comment: Installed. Now the output of `qmake --version` is: `qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''`

Comment: It seems you haven't installed qt at all ! Please run `sudo apt install qt5-default`

Comment: Wouldn't `QT` and `SDL` be installed alongside Virtualbox as you wrote in your original answer?

Comment: I am indecided between the Ubuntu repositories and the Oracle repositories: which one would be safer to install all due dependancies?

Comment: Oracle repositories will give you latest version of vbox, while Ubuntu give you stable version. If you proceed with Ubuntu, run `sudo apt install virtualbox` on terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91170/discussion-between-emmet-and-asarluhi).